# Where is Hibernate/JPA/GlassFish/Netbeans storing the data?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm learning Java EE 6 and I'm beginning with basic tutorials trying to really understand all the infrastructure and playing a little bit with it.

So I did a basic tutorial ([this](http://www.objectdb.com/tutorial/jpa/netbeans) one) about using JPA. The only difference is that I changed the ObjectDB implementation for Hibernate.

It is very simple, it has an Entity, a DAO Session Bean, a Servlet and a JSP. The only thing that it does is that you register names and it shows the names to you. I configured Hibernate to work with a postgres database and in the persistence.xml file put the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="TutorialGuestBook1PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/__default</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Everything is working ok, but I cannot see where is being saved the information that I'm saving with the sample application. I know that it must be somewhere but I query the postgres database and I cannot find it.

Where should be the information? Is something about the default datasource or something like that? Can anyone light me?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I found when I searched "GlassFish default datasouce", first hit:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2424/gksmw.html

> The `jdbc/__default` Java DB database is preconfigured with Embedded GlassFish Server. It is used when an application is deployed in Embedded GlassFish Server that uses Java Persistence but doesn't specify a data source. Embedded GlassFish Server uses the embedded Java DB database created in a temporary domain that is destroyed when Embedded GlassFish Server is stopped.

IIRC it's the same on the non-embedded, but haven't checked in awhile. Simple enough search, though.